# HTML and PHP generate pagination links

Tags: php, html

I have some PHP and html code that loads in results from my database. It shows five results per page. Let's pretend I have 1000 pages. The links for all those pages would go off the screen. Google had this problem but they fixed it by only displaying the current link as well as 5 links back and 5 links forward. I want to do something like this. I don't want to display 100 links to the various pages. Pretend the user is on page 100. I want to display the links for page 100 as well as link 95 to 105. How can I do this? Here is my code so far:

```
$page = $_GET["page"];
$pagesQuery  = mysql_query("SELECT count(id) FROM(`posts`)");
$pageNum = ceil(mysql_result($pagesQuery, 0)/5);
$start = (($page-1)*5);

$currentname = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts LIMIT $start, 5");  
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($currentname)) {
        //recieve relevant data.
        $title = $row[0];
        $desc = $row[13];
        $ID = $row[6];
        $views = $row[3];
        $user = $row[7];
        //fetch the last id from accounts table.
        $fetchlast1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allaccounts WHERE id=(SELECT MAX(id) FROM allaccounts)");
        $lastrow1 = mysql_fetch_row($fetchlast1);
        $lastid1 = $lastrow1[6];
        //acquire the username of postee.
        for ($i1=1; $i1 <= $lastid1; $i1++) { 
            $currentname1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM allaccounts WHERE id=$user");
            while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($currentname1)) {
                $username1 = $row1[0];
            }
        }

        //Format Title, description and view count.
        $title2 = rtrim($title);
        $donetitle = str_replace(" ", "-", $title2);
        $url = "articles/".$ID."/".$donetitle."";

        $donetitle = strlen($title) > 40 ? substr($title,0,40)."..." : $title;
        $donedesc = '';

        if(strlen($desc) > 150) {
            $donedesc = explode( "\n", wordwrap( $desc, 150));
            $donedesc1 = $donedesc[0] . '...';                          
        }else{
            $donedesc1 = $desc;                         
        }
        $finviews = number_format($views, 0, '.', ',');

        //Give relevant results
        if(stripos($title, $terms) !== false || stripos($desc, $terms) !== false || stripos($username1, $terms) !== false){
                if($row[10] == null){
                    $SRC = "img/tempsmall.jpg";
                }else{
                    $SRC ="generateThumbnailSmall.php?id=$ID"; 
                }
                echo "<div id = \"feature\">

                       <img src=\"$SRC\" alt = \"article thumbnail\" />
                      </div>
                        <div id = \"feature2\">
                             <a href= \"$url\" id = \"titletext\" alt = \"article title\">$donetitle</a>
                             <p id=\"resultuser\" >$username1</p>
                             <p id=\"resultp\">$donedesc1</p>
                             <a href = \"sendflag.php?title=$title&url=$url&id=$ID&userid=$user\" id = \"flag\" alt = \"flag\"><img src=\"img/icons/flag.png\"/></a><b id=\"resultview\">$finviews views</b> 

                        </div>
                      <div id = \"border\"></div>";
            }                   
}

for ($j=1; $j < $pageNum; $j++) { 
    echo "<a id =\"\" href=\"searchresults.php?search=".$terms."&page=".$j."\">".$j."</a>";
}
```

Comment: Use this generic script to implement pagination, [https://github.com/rajdeeppaul/Pagination](https://github.com/rajdeeppaul/Pagination)

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use `MySQLi` or `PDO` instead. With the above script you can easily implement pagination using `MySQLi` or `PDO` driver.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to change this:

```
for ($j=1; $j < $pageNum; $j++) { 
 echo "<a id =\"\" href=\"searchresults.php?search=".$terms."&page=".$j."\">".$j."</a>";
}
```

Here you list all links $j < $pageNum and you want to list just 10: $j <= 10 starting $j = $currentPage or $j = $currentPage - 5 if $currentPage is > 5